# WinUI: Completed callback for UIElement.Transitions property

Tags: c#, winui-3, winui

As the title says, is there a way to be notified when the `transition` in `TransitionCollection` that is assigned to `UIElement.Transitions` is completed?
It would be great if a simple sample code block is provided. Thanks in advance!

`Transition` class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.transition?view=winrt-22621

`UIElement.Transitions` property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.transitions?view=winrt-22621

```
PaneThemeTransition transition = new PaneThemeTransition();
Transitions = new TransitionCollection { transition };
```

Comment: Transitions are all builtin, there's no event and most of the time have very little customization capabilities, so you'd have to write a custom animation (storyboard) which do have a completed event https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.media.animation.timeline.completed The WinUI3 Gallery has lots of animation samples https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery

Comment: As @SimonMourier commented, you need [animations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.timeline?view=winrt-22621#timeline-derived-classes) not transitions. But probably you can [RegisterPropertyChangedCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject.registerpropertychangedcallback?view=winrt-22621) for the last transition which could be an unrecognizable transition to notify.